# How to measure the phase margin of a fully differential ampifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, phase-margin

How do you measure the phase margin of a fully differential amplifier?

We know that the output voltage of a fully differential amplifier is $$V_\text{out} = (V_\text{o+} - V_\text{o-})$$ so how do you calculate the phase margin? Do you have to consider the phase margin of a single output?

Answer (score 1):

A fully-differential amplifier has two phase margins of interest, but they are not necessarily the phase margins of the two single outputs.

Instead, after the amplifier is linearized about its operating point, one can consider the common-mode phase margin (i.e. the phase margin from the loop gain of the system as a common-mode excitation makes it way around the loop), and the differential-mode phase margin (i.e. the phase margin from the loop gain as a differential-mode excitation makes its way around the loop). Both should be stable, but the achieved and required phase margin may very well be different between the two.

Because of imperfect CMRR, there may be higher-order effects where a differential-mode excitation is weakly converted to common-mode, and then back, through multiple passes of the system. However, this is probably a fairly small effect that can be ignored for a first-pass estimate.

From the simulation point of view, Cadence Spectre/Virtuoso includes a `diffstbprobe` element that sits in the feedback network (just like a normal `iprobe` for a single-ended stability analysis). It reports either common-mode or differential-mode loopgain to the `stb` analysis itself, based on its configuration/selected attributes.